# Blank page when opening .fla file in Adobe Flash CS6

Tags: flash, adobe, fla

I have converted the document from .swf to .fla, and wanna open it in Adobe Flash. I used CS6 after CC. I opened the .fla file, but it shows a blank page instead (see the link below). I don't know why does it happen. I noticed that in the Library tab in the right, the resources (images) still exist. Any hints that I could open and edit the file?

link: http://postimg.org/image/vm88eb2az/

Comment: So you reverse engineered your .swf or someone else's swf?

Comment: it is my .swf, i converted from ppt to swf, now i want to convert it back to fla

Comment: Perhaps it is all built within code. Meaning it creates MC and Sprites and adds them as children to the Stage at run-time. What does the code of the first few frames indicate? Or perhaps they are nested within Layer 1? Are there any other scenes?